SSO not working in iOS when using AWS Cognito and Azure AD
We are using Azure AD as OIDC Identity Provider in AWS Cognito.
In iOS side, we use ASWebAuthenticationSession to show a web view and let the user login. User can login successfully but the issue is when opening Safari browser in the iPhone and going to the user's Microsoft account, the user needs to input his/her credentials.
Notes:

prefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession is set to false
We've tried to use older APIs such as SFSafariViewController and SFAuthenticationSession
We have our own Authorization and SSO is working between our app and Safari.

Anything we're missing for SSO to work between our app and Safari app?

What do you mean by "when opening Safari browser in the iPhone and going to the user's Microsoft account". Is this inside your app or outside of your app?  What website are they going to? Why would they be signed in to that web site after authenticating to your app?

@Paulw11 the steps are:


Open app and login to Microsoft account using ASWebAuthenticationsession. Again, we are using AWS Cognito and Azure AD


Open Safari app


In Safari App, open URL, for example, https://office.com


I would expect that I won't need to enter my credentials again



I would not expect the user to be logged in to office.com just because they had logged into another application. You cannot expect SSO between your app and another app

@Paulw11 I see. So I guess it’s case to case basis depending on the auth service? For example, SSO works of you logged in using Google in an app. Opening google.com in Safari does not require you to input your credentials.

It seems SSO depends on a couple of things

How do authentication services store the cookies
What API you use to login the user

Found this very useful blog from Okta that summarizes cookies sharing between Safari app, SFSafariViewController, SFAuthenticationSession, ASWebAuthenticationSession.

You should be able to create a link with the authorization token for Microsoft, then redirect your app to open the link in safari. The iPhone will leave your app to open the auth link including the token.
Then if you leave your app, you would have loaded the auth info into safari for use outside your app.
